# how to write local file via javascript using firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

May I ask, is it possible to write local file via javascript using firefox.
Something like ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") in IE.
Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot read/write local files with a client side script language directly. It would have security implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is to send the file to Firefox as a download. So user can choose where to store this file.

Navigators can not act directly on local file system because of security implications!